# Attempted import error: 'AiFillMessage' is not exported from 'react-icons/fa' (imported as 'MessengerIcon')

Tags: reactjs, frontend, icons

I was trying to use react icons but im getting this error.

I already downloaded the icons using both

yarn add react-icons --save

and

yarn add react-icons

but they aren't working which really confused me.

Here is how I used them:-

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./index.css";
import { BsBell as BellIcon } from "react-icons/fa";
import { AiFillMessage as MessengerIcon } from "react-icons/fa";
import { AiOutlineCaretDown as CaretIcon } from "react-icons/fa";
import { AiOutlinePlus as PlusIcon } from "react-icons/fa";
import { BiCog as CogIcon } from "react-icons/fa";
import { GoChevronDown as ChevronIcon } from "react-icons/fa";
import { AiOutlineArrowDown as ArrowIcon } from "react-icons/fa";
import { AiOutlineThunderbolt as BoltIcon } from "react-icons/fa";

import { CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Navbar2>
        <NavItem icon={<PlusIcon />} />
        <NavItem icon={<BellIcon />} />
        <NavItem icon={<MessengerIcon />} />
        <NavItem icon={<CaretIcon />}>
          <DropdownMenu></DropdownMenu>
        </NavItem>
      </Navbar2>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/memory" element={<Memory />} />
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <>
              <AMBox />
              <Experience />
              <Projects />
              <Education />
            </>
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Response to question change:

Ant Icons need to be imported from the ant icons folder not the font awesome one. Try this:

```
import { AiFillMessage as MessengerIcon } from "react-icons/ai";
```

You'll need to do that for all the ant icons.

Original (no longer relevant).

I use react-icons and my own svgs in react apps. I think you might be confused about the react-icons package. To use an icon from react-app you want something like:

```
import { FaBell } from 'react-icons/fa';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Navbar>
              <NavItem><FaBell/></NavItem>
            </Navbar>
        </Router>
}
```

Using your own svgs is a different thing. It requires setting up webpack or using other js packages. It also depends on if you're using create-react-app or vanilla webpack. There's lots of guides and documentation depending on your setup.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I actually tried that and I got this error. Just updated my question ^

Comment: @robert Updated my answer to be relevant to your new question.